# What's wrong with this basil plant's leaves?

Tags: watering, herbs, basil

Bought this basil about 2 weeks ago. It dried out a lot so I gave it a good soak by putting it in a pan full of water so the water would go up from the bottom.

Now the ends of some leaves have gone brown. Has this been caused by too much water? how often should I water it?

It's from a garden centre, not the supermarket 'living basil' pots.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Too much water. Basil is a Mediterranean plant, it doesn't need much water. BTW the plant needs much more sun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would transplant this guy into a larger pot...2 or 3" larger in diameter using ONLY potting soil.  I would also cut this guy down to one foot high.  Do not water too often! Have you fertilized?  Use Dr. Earth's 5-5-5 all purpose or Growilla 2-5-4 and use HALF of what the directions tell you to use.

If you have a covered patio that is the perfect place for this plant during the growing season.  Never out in the direct sun without appropriate acclimatization.  Basil can grow fairly well in the sun of a southern kitchen window.